# How to do groupby in pandas with part of date string?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

```
        Date Description 
0  6/09/2012      Amazon
1  6/09/2012      iTunes
2  6/08/2012      iTunes
3  6/08/2012    Building
4  6/08/2012   Slicehost
```

I have a `DataFrame` like the above. I can pick out the day part of the above datestring using a function get_day() like this:

```
def get_day(date_string):
    d = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y')
    return d.day
```

Now how do I pass this function to the above DataFrame to get groupby going on the day rather than the datestring itself. Couldn't figure it out from looking at the docs. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(get_day)
```

but I would convert the date strings to datetime objects first anyway.

Another problem is that you're calling `.day` which returns a day of month (number 1-31). You probably want to call `.date()`:

```
def get_day(date_string):
    return datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

or directly

```
df.groupby(lambda x: datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y').date())
```

Comment: I guess my problem is that the index of that column is not date, rather those numbers by the side. Suppose instead of get_day we have def print_given(given): print given, and we do df.groupby(print_given) I see 0,1,2... printed and not the 6/09/2012 etc.