# Grouping Pandas DataFrame by date

Tags: datetime, python-2.7, group-by, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that includes a `date` column. Elements of that column are of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`.

I'd like to group the dataframe by date, but exclude timestamp information that is more granular that date (ie. grouping by date, where all `Feb 23, 2011` are grouped). I know how to express this in SQL, but am quite new to Pandas.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975690/how-to-do-groupby-in-pandas-with-part-of-date-string) does something very similar, but I don't understand the code and it uses `datetime` objects.

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html), I don't even understand how to retrieve the date from a Pandas Timestamp object. I could convert to `datetime` object, but that seems very roundabout.

---

As requested, the output of `df.head()`:

```
    date    show    network timed   session_id
0   2011-12-03 02:48:52  Monk    TV38    670     00003DA9-01D2-E7A9-4177-203BE6A9E2BA    
1   2011-12-03 03:00:09  WBZ News    TV38    205     00003DA9-01D2-E7A9-4177-203BE6A9E2BA
2   2011-12-03 03:04:04  Dateline NBC    NBC     30  00003DA9-01D2-E7A9-4177-203BE6A9E2BA
3   2011-12-03 03:04:35  20/20   ABC     25  00003DA9-01D2-E7A9-4177-203BE6A9E2BA
4   2011-12-03 03:04:56  College Football    FOX     55  00003DA9-01D2-E7A9-4177-203BE6A9E2BA
```

Comment: the output of you df.head() will be welcomed here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `normalize` DatetimeIndex method (which takes it to midnight that day):

```
In [11]: df['date']
Out[11]: 
0   2011-12-03 02:48:52
1   2011-12-03 03:00:09
2   2011-12-03 03:04:04
3   2011-12-03 03:04:35
4   2011-12-03 03:04:56
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [12]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).normalize()
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-12-03 00:00:00, ..., 2011-12-03 00:00:00]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

And you can groupby this:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).normalize())
```

---

In 0.15 you'll have access to the dt attribute, so can write this as:

```
g = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.normalize())
```

Comment: Another alternative: `pd.DatetimeIndex(df["date"]).date` instead.  One advantage is that many common things you'd want to group by are built-in: `.month`, `.year`, `.hour`, etc.

Comment: It seems this approach ignores timezones, but patrickrm101's doesn't.

Comment: @DavidChouinard really? That sounds like a bug, it would be posting an issue on github https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear if you are trying to groupby and aggregate (like in SQL) or create an index with a date instead of a timestamp.

If you're trying to groupby and aggregrate, you could do it this way:

```
df.groupby(df.set_index('date').index.date).mean()
```

Timeseries indexes have datetime properites like day, date, etc. That will aggregate the timed column since it's the only numeric column.

If you're trying to create an index with a date level, you could do something like:

```
import datetime
df.set_index(['date', df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.date(x))], inplace=True)
df.index.names = ['timestamp', 'daydate']
```

This will give you a multiindex with the timestamp and a date . If you don't want the index to be permanent, drop the inplace= argument.

Comment: I meant groupby and aggregate. It seems your method is a bit more generic that Andy Hayden's (ie. works for more than just days).